# How to design stack-like icons like Apple and Bootstrap do, in Sketch?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, sketch-app, apple, bootstrap

Sorry if this is a really stupid question or something really easy, I'm just a backend developer who has no talent with design.

I'm actually programming a Dynamic Library for jailbroken iOS devices that allows you to create multiple enviroments.

I would like to create an icon like this one apple made for the **Siri Kit**:

[image: Apple's Siri Kit icon]

Or something like the **Bootstrap logo**:
[image: Bootstrap logo]
I already have the image that would go on the topside of the stack and the color scheme for the icon, just need to know how to create that stack.

Any help would be appreciated. I can use either Sketch or Photoshop to do this.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: are you want to create that kind of layer stack via code or you want separate standalone image to use directly? and please provide us if you want to draw it in tools then which tools (illustrator,photoshop,gimp etc)

Comment: @DesignPhoenix I just want to create an icon, doesn't matter whether it is via code or it is a separate image, also because with one **.psd** file I can export to svg (which I suppose that is what you refer by "code") or to a separate .png. I can use Photoshop for that, but do not know how

Comment: well if you have photoshop then it's clear then letme edit your question

Comment: Icons and logos are usually created using vector editing software - such as Illustrator, CorelDraw, Affinity Designer, Inkscape (which is free).  Photoshop is not ideal for logos and icons because it's raster software. Forget Photoshop, go vector!

Comment: I just said that I could use Photoshop because I didn't think Sketch would be good for doing this type of work. I just have Photoshop or Sketch so I can't use neither Illustrator, CorelDraw nor Affinity Designer, but I'll try to use Inkscape.

Thank you so much guys for help

Comment: Sketch is a vector image editor - perfect for the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Photoshop is not the right tool to do this kind of jobs because the limitation in shape editing tools, it would be better to use a vector program like Illustrator. Anyway, here is an approach in a 300px x 300px RGB Photoshop document.

## Shape

- Click the **Rounded Rectangle Tool** and at the top options menu set `Shape` and 40px corner
- Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and make a square.

[image: square]

- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Win to transform and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to rotate the shape 45º

[image: rotate]

- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply the transformation

  - Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Win to transform and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> to scale the shape from the top to the center

[image: second shape]

- This is one of the shapes. Duplicate the layers and change the colors to get the other two. Double click the layer to open the **Effects Panel** and add the Drop Shadow Effect

[image: Three shapes]

## Volume

- Duplicate the main shape layer, fill it with 100% black
- Click the layer with the right mouse button and choose **Rasterize Layer**
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> Mac or Win to fill and choose White, 100% mode Behind:

[image: Fill panel]

- Menu **Filter** → **Blur** → **Motion Blur**

[image: Motion Blur]

- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> Win to open the **Levels Panel** and move the midtones slider to the right

[image: levels]

- Menu **Select** → **Color Range** →  **Shadows** to get the volume selection
- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> Win to create a **Layer Via Copy**

[image]

- Double click the *Volume Layer* to add a **Color Overlay**, Overlay blending mode and a **Gradient Overlay** from dark grey to light grey

[image: Color & gradient]

- Duplicate the *Volume Layer* and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Win while clicking the *Volume* thumbnail to load the transparency selection and click the Mask Icon
- Double click the layer to change the Color Overlay
- Unlink the mask clicking the chain icon and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> to move up the content
- Put the *Original Shape Layer* on top

[image: Volume]

Comment: thank you so much for this. One last question: can I use sketch for this?

Comment: I'm not a Sketch user, but since it's a vector program, I guess it will be better than Photoshop to design icons.

Comment: ok, perfect. Also, and now I promise it is the last question of all. Can you please send me the .psd file for the last icon? I managed to do the bootstrap one, but Im having quite few problems with the apple one.

Comment: can you please send me the .psd file of the volume icon (the last one). I can't manage to do this one. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Sorry, I use to delete the files after answering. Try to follow the step by step again, I'm sure you will manage to get it.

Comment: @iAlex11: Please note that we do not like to do your work for free here; we prefer you to teach you how to do it. Therefore, please refrain from asking users for files that allow you to bypass your problem.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I'm not asking him to send me the file to bypass my problem, it is just that Im having problems with doing the icon so I just wondered if he could send me the file so I could see what I was doing wrong as I'm following the instructions step by step. But don't worry, I wont ask for files again, sorry.

Thanks for teaching me, I'm new to this things

Comment: @Danielillo don't worry, I'll try to fix it by myself, which is what I'm supposed to do. Thanks for all

Comment: How do I choose 100% white mode Behind in Photoshop CC 2019? Sorry for annoying you

Comment: Answer updated with a screen capture

Answer (score 2):

Since you stated that you could use either Photoshop or Sketch, I wanted to mimic 
@Danielillo's answer but using Sketch this time.

Disclaimer: The result is far from perfect, I'll just explain the different steps I've taken to *almost* recreate the Bootstrap logo.

### 1. Shape

First, we'll insert a rounder corner rectangle into our blank Sketch page using **Insert → Shape → Rounded**.
Tip: holding <kbd>alt</kbd> forces your rectangle to actually be a square.

[image]

We can then remove the border of the freshly created square on the right panel (uncheck the border checkbox) and add accentuate the rounded corners on the same panel (I set it to **35** but that was a total guess).
We're also going to rotate the rectangle using the same panel (go with **45°**)

[image]

While our rectangle is still selected, we can select the transform menu **Layer → Transform → Transform** and manipulate our shape to reflect the skewed Bootstrap logo. Here I have to admit that I just use the logo you provided (dragged and dropped into the Sketch file) as an overlay to reflect its shape. I change the color and the opacity to the new rectangle to make the task easier. There might be a more robust way to do that and if someone has a tip I'd gladly hear it.

**Tip:** don't forget to specify the order of the elements in the Sketch file using the left panel (just drag and drop the shapes, the Bootstrap logo (png) should be at the end of the list).

[image: The new rectangle (in orange) and the Bootstrap logo (png) are superimposed]

### 2. Stack

In the next step we are going to duplicate (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>) the rectangle two times and position those two new rectangles thanks to the PNG that currently lives under our vectorial drawing.

[image]

### 3. Colors and shadows

The gradient used in the Bootstrap logo will be replicated thanks to the eyedropper tool. Select the top rectangle and change the color to a linear gradient. The two colors used for the gradient can be selected by clicking the left and right dots in the slider below the gradient type option (see picture).

[image]

We are going to click the slider's left dot (the *starting* color of the gradient) and click the eyedropper to select the top color of the Bootstrap logo's first layer. The same steps are applied to the *ending* color of the gradient with the corresponding color.
We need to play a little bit the gradient colors and apply those to the three rectangles of our stack.

We can also add a shadow (gray shadow, opacity at **50%**) and position it a little bit under every rectangle (**y=6**, again, a complete guess).

Here are the settings for the almost finished stack:

[image]

### 4. B letter

Last step, the B letter.
Simply insert a text (**Insert → Text**) and add a capital **B** with the **Verdana** font and the **Regular** font weight (font-size will depend on the size of the previously created shapes).

We then convert the letter to outlines (the text layer will be converted to a vector shape) using **Layer → Convert to Outlines** so we can transform it and give it the *skewed* styled from the Bootstrap logo.

Use the steps described in first section of this post to Transform the newly created converted text and place it in the middle of the top rectangle.

And here we are:

[image]

It's far from perfect (colors aren't accurate, shapes are not the exact same ones and the letter is not perfectly skewed but... it's a start I guess).

Comment: thanks, this can also help me a lot! I'd upvote you but I cant as I do not have enough reputation.

Comment: Glad I can help! :)